# Horizontal scroll in a parent div containing floated child divs

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">2001</div>
    <div class="child">2O02</div>
    <div class="child">2003</div>
    <div class="child">2004</div>
    <div class="child">2005</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent{
width:100%;
overflow:auto;
}

.Child{
float:left;
width:20px;
}
```

The child content is always overflowing, and this is good. But I want to be able to scroll horizontally in the parent div, to see the last child divs.

Here is a screenshot of the result as I have it:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJNj8.jpg)

How can I do that to make is scroll horizontally?

Comment: you have to clear the floats (at the end of #parent) Then give #parent a set a height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all childs in a single row, you have to add second "parent" DIV and set it's width (combined widths of all children for a single row):

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="parent2">
        <div class="child">2001</div>
        <div class="child">2002</div>
        <div class="child">2003</div>
        <div class="child">2004</div>
        <div class="child">2005</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}


#parent2{
    width:1000px;
}

.child{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
```